# Youtube Player on Android - endless loading

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

`YoutubePlayer` shows endless loading when try to `play` a song with `YoutubePlayerAPI` in particular with `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` for Android. It happens randomly. Sometimes the loading fails with `INTERNAL_ERROR`. Please see attached images

Strange - because native `Youtube app` is able to `load and play video` properly and without any delay.

Please advise what might be the reason of such issues and how to fix them. Thanks in advance

EDIT: I do receive onVideoStarted callback, but still video doesn't play

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

See this answer and try to do the same [YouTubePlayerFragment backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521198/youtubeplayerfragment-backstack/34006802#34006802). I think your problem has same cause as mine. Also check logcat output for errors (it could be obfuscated, and out of application scope, so check 'No filters' in logcat)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this really answers the questions, but I was having a similar issue with infinite loading.

Basically I would play a video using a player fragment, exit the video, and then the next video I would try to play would display an infinite loading indicator.

This issue was only happening on certain devices.

Since I was using the latest version of the youtube api, I updated the youtube app on the problematic devices and that seemed to resolve the issue.

I know that "update the youtube app" isn't a great answer, but it did resolve odd issues I was experiencing.

Hope this helps.