# Android YouTubePlayerApi: YouTubePlayer keeps on loading

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using YouTubePlayerAPI and YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in my app. Recently, I found that YouTubePlayer keeps on loading in first page when backed from secondary page. But I couldn't find out what is causing it. I've been looking for information but I haven't found anything useful.

My testing methodology:
Click the TextView to start the secondary page. Go back, the question has appeared.

Here is my code：

```
public class FragmentDemoActivity extends Activity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragments_demo);

        TextView tvDes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_start_another);
        tvDes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), FragmentDemoActivity.class));
            }
        });

        YouTubePlayerFragmentWrap youTubePlayerFragment =
                (YouTubePlayerFragmentWrap) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you given internet permission in menifest? and are you passing proper url to play? Any error logs?

Comment: Try to follow the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521198). The user here experience the same issue that you have, a video that doesn't play and only keeps loading. So try to follow his workaround by extending the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and check if it works on you.

Comment: @KENdi I had tried this answer before this issue. Thank you any way.

Comment: @Harry All you mentioned had been included, the video can be played, but endless loading after backed from secondary page.